# Directly accessing Webshot images in Shiny

Tags: r, shiny

Aim:  Create a screenshot of a website that is shown automatically when the user inputs a Gene name e.g. TP53, NAPRT

Problem: while this works locally, it fails when I publish it online. I suspect that this is because the files downloaded from webshot are no longer accessible. I have tried to specify the file name wiht www/Filename.png but this works both offline for all the genes and online for only those which had already been created before and thus the pictures already existed in the www

As you can see, running it R works, but publishing it doesn't.

````
library(webshot)

# Define UI for application that draws a histogram
ui <- fluidPage(
  textInput("gene", "Gene symbol", value = "TP53"),
  imageOutput('myImage')
)

# Define server logic required to draw a histogram
server <- function(input, output) {
  output$myImage <- renderImage({
   outfile <- paste(input$gene,'.png', sep="") 

    owd <- setwd(tempdir())
    webshot(paste('http://ualcan.path.uab.edu/cgi-bin/Pan-cancer.pl?genenam',input$gene,sep="="),
            outfile,
            selector = '#banner3',
            delay = 2,
            expand = c(0,40,0,0))
    # Return a list containing the filename
    list(src = outfile,
         contentType = 'image/png',
         width = 600,
         height = 450,
         alt = "This is alternate text")
  }, deleteFile = FALSE)
    }

# Run the application 
shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)```
````

Comment: Interesting approach. Have you considered making a pdf/html report with Rmd (which you can parameterize)?

Comment: I did and I am also making that which doesn't have this problem. The idea here is that the rest of my lab doesn't have access to my R environment and thus they can access these resources without me needed to produce reports for them. Also having it in a website for anyone is really useful. Maybe there is a different way to screenshot websites in R? or a way to save webshots in variables instead of downloading them?

Comment: Where are you publishing your app online? I'm guessing that it's a problem with not having write permissions to somewhere in the folder structure of the server.

Comment: I'm publishing directly to Shinyapps.io

Comment: Have you looked at the logs if there's any indication what is going awry?

Comment: Thank you so much for suggesting this! Didn't know logs were kept #beginner. Solved my problem by webshot::install_phantomjs() which wasn't part of the script by preinstalled on my PC